# How to overflow/expand/bleed a Bootstrap column to the edge of the viewport?

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, grid, responsive

I am attempting to recreate the search page UI of Airbnb (for example https://www.airbnb.nl/s/Paris/homes). Unfortunately I experience some difficulties expanding the map section to the far right edge of the viewport.

This is what I need: https://i.ibb.co/zrpwYhC/Artboard.jpg

There are some related questions and answers here on Stack Overflow.
However they seem to not follow the grid system, require Javascript or have a (extremely high) width set to the expanded element.

What I have tried myself is absolutely positioning the map to the right (outside of the grid system) and giving it a specific width. This works but it's not preferable.

Also I have checked Airbnb's source code but they seem to have a custom grid, which I don't understand well due to my limited knowledge.

I have created a custom base CSS and HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwhgpzrt/

```css
.suggestions {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.result-wrapper {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.result {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.map-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lawngreen;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="suggestions">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="result-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12"><div class="result">Result here</div></div>
                        <div class="col-12"><div class="result">Result here</div></div>
                        <div class="col-12"><div class="result">Result here</div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="map-wrapper">Google Map here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I expect the map element to follow the grid system of Bootstrap but expand/bleed to and exactly end at the right edge of the viewport.

Most important is that the solution should follow the Bootstrap grid system. Preferably it would be a CSS only solution as well.

Could anyone push me into the right direction? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

override bootdtrap's default max-width and padding specs of .container class

1. set max-width to 100%.
2. set padding to 0;

Set margin-right:0px in .row class

Set padding-right to 0 in the .col-4 class wrapping the map element

Also give a margin-left value in .suggestions class (preferably in percentage values) to maintain a left space, if you want.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! What you're suggesting is similar to the .container-fluid class provided by Bootstrap itself. This in combination with removing the right padding of the map wrapper (.col-4) roughly provides the behavior I require for the map. Though changing the .container class also results in the expansion of the results wrapper (.col-8). I require this column to maintain the default behavior that a normal .container class provides. Applying a margin-left is not feasible unfortunately. I have created an image to illustrate this: https://i.ibb.co/zrpwYhC/Artboard.jpg

Comment: Sorry I forgot about .container-fluid class. But I think using .container fluid you  can achieve what you need. Simply set the width to 90%(you  can change accordingly) and margin-right to 0 of .container-fluid class. Also remove the padding-right of .col-4(set to 0). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` first. Doing so, the whole view-port is occupied. And then, use `.offset-*` to get the left side gap.

#### Offsetting columns

> You can offset grid columns in two ways: our responsive .offset- grid
>   classes and our margin utilities. Grid classes are sized to match
>   columns while margins are more useful for quick layouts where the
>   width of the offset is variable. - [getBootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Use `.pr-0` on the map column to remove its padding-right.

```css
.suggestions {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.result-wrapper {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.result {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.map-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lawngreen;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="suggestions">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-2 col">
        <div class="result-wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="result">Result here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="result">Result here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="result">Result here</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 pr-0">
        <div class="map-wrapper">Google Map here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have used `.offset-2`. Change it if the gap is more/less than what you wish to have.  Use `.col` instead of `.col-8` as it is easier to maintain. Otherwise, calculate which `.col-*` you need to use. In this case, you need `.col-6` since `.col-6 = .col-12 - (.col-4 + .col-2)`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEqQKm